# All-time top questions

Tags: feature-request, questions

At Workplace, and any SE site for that matter, you can choose to sort questions in a number of ways. There's active, featured, hot, top questions this week, and top questions this month. Why isn't there a list of top questions of all time? I think it would be useful, particularly for someone new who just wants to browse. It also would make some of the often-duplicated questions easier to find without keeping them in favorites.

Would it be possible to create this feature (maybe for all of SE)? Or maybe there's already a way to view this that I don't know about?

A similar list could maybe be created for all-time best answers, though I'm sure there would be a lot of overlap between the two lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this? [Questions sorted by vote count](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes). If you click on "Questions" you see some other sort options.

Those sort options don't exist if you hit the main homepage [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), though...

You can also search [all answers based on vote count](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aanswer). I'm not sure you can more easily find that, though I use the "is:question" and "is:answer" search criteria pretty often. That pulls up a few other sort criteria.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that functionality had to exist somewhere! :)

Comment: @DavidK glad to help. Some things about SE are confusing, this is one of them...

Answer (score 6):

There is the [Greatest Hits](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits) list.  I don't know where it's linked (if anywhere!), but somebody tipped me off about it a while back and I just construct the URL myself (sitname/questions/greatest-hits). There's more information about it in [an old post on The Overflow blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/24/stack-exchanges-greatest-hits/) which states:

> For better or worse, these questions are what the world will see and remember your site for...

What makes a question a Greatest Hit?  This is a little vague, but the page there says:

> Questions that got a large amount of views or a large amount of feedback.
>
> The current algorithm divides the number of page views with the total amount of question and answer feedback received (adding a bonus for high view counts), excluding questions with less views than the median :- X.

(The median of the number of views 'X' is dynamically calculated.)

I believe the "feedback" it's talking about is the anonymous feedback that is generated if somebody who's not logged in clicks on a voting button.

Comment: Oh neat, never saw that before.

Comment: This is great! I wonder why it's not linked on the questions paged.